# OnSwipe transition in MotionScene, applied to ScrollView is not working

Tags: android, scrollview, android-motionlayout

At this moment I'm trying to understand MotionLayout  (in a "test app") to apply it to a bigger app.

What I'm trying is to simulate the collapsable toolbar.

I did a layout with a couple of images, and ScrollView:

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motion_l"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_test"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showPaths="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Awsome title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent "
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent " />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/background_image">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_test"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_test"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/background_image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Then I created the MotionScene Layout to handle the transition:

**MotionScene xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/scroll_view"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/background_image"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/logo"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/background_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textColor"
                app:customColorValue="#000000" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/background_image"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="255" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/logo"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/background_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                app:customIntegerValue="255" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleX="1.0"
            android:scaleY="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent "
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textColor"
                app:customColorValue="#ffffff" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

And here is where I have the problem. The animation works quite good, but ONLY if I do the gesture in the ImageView. If do the gesture in the ScrollView , the transition is ignored.

As you can see in the `OnSwipe` the `touchAnchorID` is applied to the scrollView.

Maybe is not possible to apply to ScrollView? In that case, which solution can be applied?

Because in the "real project" the view, has been done with ScrollView.

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Comment: Hi @Vodet ! Not actually, finally in the project was discarted this type of "feature", so I stopped searching for a solution. Maybe in a future a I have to come back, because designers are talking about the same behaviour. Sorry!!

Comment: @Shudy Have you tried replacing the ScrollView with a NestedScrollView? Tried that with your example and it seems to work quite well.